# Add a new item on laravel 4 using different tables

Tags: php, laravel-4, addition

***This is my Items model . Now i want to add a new item but i get this error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048***

```
<?php

class Items extends Eloquent
{

protected $guarded = [
    'id',
];

protected $fillable = [
    'name',
    'description',
    'price',
    'brand',


];

protected $table = 'items';

public function user()
{
    return $this->hasOne('User', 'user_ID', 'id');
}

public function size()
{
    return DB::table('sizes')->select('size')
        ->where('id', $this->size_ID)->first()->size;
}

public function color()
{
    return DB::table('colors')->select('color')
        ->where('id', $this->color_ID)->first()->color;
}

public function condition()
{
    return DB::table('conditions')->select('type')
        ->where('id', $this->condition_ID)->first()->type;
}

public function category()
{
    return DB::table('categories')->select('category')
        ->where('id', $this->category_ID)->first()->category;
}

public function images()
{
    return DB::table('images')->select('image')
        ->where('item_id', $this->id)->first()->image;
}

}
```

**And this is my post method to save item.**

```
     public function store()
     {

     $item = new Items;
        $item->user_ID = Auth::id();
        $item->name = Input::get('name');
        $item->description = Input::get('description');
        $item->price = Input::get('price');
        $item->brand = Input::get('brand');
        $item->category = Input::get('Category');
        $item->condition = Input::get('Condition');
        $item->color = Input::get('Color');


        $item->save();


       }
```

**Here is a picture of category table , condition and color table has the same logic.**
 http://imgur.com/9NCMYui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a relationship between User and Item while not using it. 
You can set the populate the relationship manually by filling in the id yourself, but then you don't use the power of the Eloquent ORM.

What I would suggest is getting the current user.
And saving it like this.

```
$item->user()->save($user);
```

I suggest for the name of the class Item and not Items.
I find it having much more logic and so do most of the programmers.
The table can still be called items.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! My explanation in the question was not very clever. As it is shown in the picture i have a category table. My idea was like this : when user input techonolgy category on new item , on items table category_id would be 1. The same thing for condition and color ! I really have no idea how to do this since i am a beginner in laravel and php too .